# PostgreSQL on Ubuntu - Using conf files for recovery

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu LTS 10.04.02 server version. I use pg_standby to restore the data and for database recovery created a recovery.conf and placed it on /etc/postgresql/8.4/main where rest of conf files present and tried to start the DB using

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

expecting the service to recognize that I am doing a recovery using recovery.conf. I found this file was ignored. Then, I had to copy all *.conf file to my data directory (in my case /dbdata/data) and then, instead of using script from init.d, I had to start the database from 'postgres' user with

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl -D /dbdata/proddata  -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log start
```

How I can make my recovery procedure to obey /etc/init.d/postgresql start|stop|restart
or to have pg_ctl command to look for conf files /etc/postgresql/8.4/main ?

**Note : I am relatively newbie to PostgreSQL and to database administration in general**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `recovery.conf` file needs to go into the data directory (`/var/lib/postgresql/...`).  The other configuration files can stay where they are (`/etc/postgresql/...`).  Then a normal restart should do what you want.

Comment: I am yet to validate it. but accepting the answer as it looks correct and I will be taking few days to validate them. Thanks Peter.

Comment: It does not seem to look at /etc/postgresql/..., I had to keep postgresql.conf also in data directory. Probably this is specific to Ubuntu.